# Randomizing Select subquery in MySQL when using GroupBy

Tags: mysql

I have the query that generates 100 random flat rows.
Result needs to be distinct, which means, you **cannot have the exact** same country, city and street - that is where the `Group By` is handy.

it works, besides the following:

It connects (joins), country, cities and streets and joins subquery **members** (this is the issue).

Join is 1 to 1 to 1, however, **members** can have a multiple members per country.

Issue is that currently the query result **is always the first member** of that country.

Note that duplicate members is fine in different rows, but at least they will be randomized and not always return first member.

I do not want to get into adding nulls if a duplicate member appears, if possible it would be good, but not must.

```
SELECT 
    country.guid,
    country.Name AS 'country name',
    country.Area_id,
    country_cities.guid,
    country_cities.name AS 'city name',
    country_streets.guid,
    country_streets.name AS 'country streets',
    memebers.name.guid,
    memebers.name AS 'street members'
FROM
    country
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        street_members.country_id, guid, name
    FROM
        street_members) memebers ON memebers.country_id = country.id
        JOIN
    country_cities ON country_cities.country_id = country.id
        JOIN
    country_streets ON country_streets.city_id = country_cities.id

GROUP BY country.guid , country_cities.guid , country_streets.guid
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you randomized the order of each of your joined tables? I'm guessing that `country` is the lightest table of them all, so in your example, randomization would just pick 100 random countries and join them with the first `street_member`, `country_city` and `country_street`.

Comment: umm, because of the `GROUP BY`  and the way MySQL fetch data with `LIMIT` there is some kind of artificial randomness, but it's just assumption. I do get different data each query execution (aka not first from each type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny one, I finally made it work by adding the columns we wanted in the subquery in a `group by`, like this :

```
SELECT 
    country.guid,
    country.Name AS 'country name',
    country.Area_id,
    country_cities.guid,
    country_cities.name AS 'city name',
    country_streets.guid,
    country_streets.name AS 'country streets',
    memebers.name.guid,
    memebers.name AS 'street members'
FROM
    country
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        RAND() as seed, country_id, guid, name
    FROM
        street_members GROUP BY seed, name, guid,country_id ORDER BY seed) memebers ON memebers.country_id = country.id
        JOIN
    country_cities ON country_cities.country_id = country.id
        JOIN
    country_streets ON country_streets.city_id = country_cities.id
GROUP BY country.guid , country_cities.guid , country_streets.guid
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Did not test the whole request, but tested the trick on one of my DB and it work.

Comment: Indeed funny one, it does work! The `RAND() as seed` does the trick. It's enough to use `GROUP BY seed order by seed`

Comment: Next level is to view different **members.name** for the same country, currently if shows the same **members.name** for the same country, but different one at each query.

Comment: You should keep some fields int the `GROUP BY` (at least the table id), because you could be incredibly unlucky and get two identical seeds, hence grouping two unrelated lines.To get different members for the same country, the easiest way is to join `street_members` to `country_streets` instead. You can also add a `JOIN country_cities` and a `JOIN country_streets` in the subquery, then add those id in the `memebers` join condition. Either way you need to move the subquery after `country_streets`.

Comment: _"the easiest way is to join street_members to country_streets instead"_ instead of the subquery?

Comment: My bad, I should have said : the easiest way is to join the subquery to `country_streets` instead of `country` (if possible to add or use some `country_streets_id`).

Comment: nope :( i don't have relation between `country_streets` and `street_members`. Might be issue to add.

Comment: Proceeded the question here, since it's a new topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912857/randomizing-select-subquery-in-mysql-using-groupby-with-different-random-subquer

Comment: I was wondering, does this query should generate random results? It feels that when i am using it (quite a lot) that there are some repeating country, city, streets statistically much more than others. bizzare, what do you think?

Comment: Well, first according to [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) the rand function "is not meant to be a perfect random generator". Second, countries with more members should have more chance to appear (because we get 100 random members). Third, maybe try to swap the subquery and the `country` table in the join (`select subquery left join country...`). Depending on how MySQL execute the request it may improve the randomness (no guarantee here ^^).