# Randomizing Select SubQuery in MySQL using GroupBy with different random SubQuery results

Tags: mysql

How to show different `members.name` for the same country, currently if shows the same `members.name` for the same country, but different one at each query execution.

Based on previous question: [Randomizing Select subquery in MySQL when using GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905653/randomizing-select-subquery-in-mysql-when-using-groupby/50906480?noredirect=1#comment88825131_50906480)

The query:

```
 SELECT 
        country.guid,
        country.Name AS 'country name',
        country.Area_id,
        country_cities.guid,
        country_cities.name AS 'city name',
        country_streets.guid,
        country_streets.name AS 'country streets',
        memebers.name.guid,
        memebers.name AS 'street members'
    FROM
        country
            JOIN
        (SELECT 
            RAND() as seed, country_id, guid, name
        FROM
            street_members GROUP BY seed, name, guid,country_id ORDER BY seed) memebers ON memebers.country_id = country.id
            JOIN
        country_cities ON country_cities.country_id = country.id
            JOIN
        country_streets ON country_streets.city_id = country_cities.id
    GROUP BY country.guid , country_cities.guid , country_streets.guid
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Comment: Provide example data in a http://sqlfiddle.com or https://www.db-fiddle.com/ and provide "possible" expected results as formatted text make multiple "possible" results so we can see which data is randomized and which is not.

Comment: You can also include a link to the previous question to give some context.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in a previous question, you don't have a direct link between `country_streets` and `street_members`, so I only see the following solution :

```
SELECT 
        country.guid,
        country.Name AS 'country name',
        country.Area_id,
        country_cities.guid,
        country_cities.name AS 'city name',
        country_streets.guid,
        country_streets.name AS 'country streets',
        memebers.name.guid,
        memebers.name AS 'street members'
    FROM
        country
            JOIN
        country_cities ON country_cities.country_id = country.id
            JOIN
        country_streets ON country_streets.city_id = country_cities.id
            JOIN
        (SELECT 
            RAND() as seed, country_id, city_id, cs.id as streets_id, guid, name
         FROM
            street_members sm 
            JOIN country_cities cc ON sm.country_id = cc.country_id 
            JOIN country_streets cs ON cs.city_id = cc.country_id 
         GROUP BY seed, name, guid,country_id,city_id,streets_id ORDER BY seed
        ) memebers ON memebers.streets_id=country_streets.id
    GROUP BY country.guid , country_cities.guid , country_streets.guid
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Again it's not tested on your specific database (and could surely be improved here and there) but you get the idea.

Comment: Can't seem to make this work correctly, It should work, i guess i missed something, but it is becoming too complex to maintain and might be also slow because of all joins. I am sticking with your previous solution. I appreciate your assistance !

Comment: You're welcome ! Too bad it's not working, if you ever want to try again just add your tables description in the question.

Comment: It might be working. This example field names is a different than my field names, to make it more readable here.